# Export vector file in DXF

Tags: raster, vector, dxf

I used QGIS a lot last year for Dutch cadastral maps purposes. Since December 2020 I notice something has changed when I export maps to dxf. Exports have always been as Vectorfile. Lately they become rasterfiles.

Does anyone know how I could get exports back in vector?
Nothing has changed in the inputfiles (zip)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure nothing changed in your QGIS file ? I ask because using transparency or layer/symbol effect could cause the rasterization so even a small symbology change like setting a layer with transparency may have caused this behaviour

Comment: I don't think I've changed anything. I tried the same procedure on a different pc where I newly install QGIS and problem also occurs.